# Differences of File in HTML5 and HTML4

Tags: html

I want to know the differences of File API in html5 and previous version.

Comment: Since when does `html` have `API`?

Comment: @Raghuram Since [November 17th, 2009](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-FileAPI-20091117/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is -

`HTML5` has File API and `HTML4` does not have any File api.

Comment: HTML 5 does not have a File API, and hasn't had for several years.

Answer (score 2):

The [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) is an independent specification. Support in browsers is irrespective of the version of HTML being used (although might be influenced by Doctype switching between Quirks/Standards modes).

I believe it started out life as part of HTML 5, but is not in the current version of it and will not be included in the final version of it. It was never a part of the HTML 4 specification.